# Power Apps add prefix to attachments that are added to SharePoint list

Tags: forms, function, sharepoint, powerapps

I have a PowerApps form where users can add attachments that are the added to a sharepoint list, I would like to add a prefix to the file names i.e. plan.pdf becomes xxx-plan.pdf before they are added to sharepoint.

Thanks

Comment: How are you submitting the attachments to SharePoint currently, using SubmitForm function or using Power automate flow?